# How to download all files in aws S3folder in local machine using node js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an S3 bucket which has a folder with some files I want to download all the files in that folder to the local machine folder I tried for the single file it's working how to download multiple files.

As per below code in key folderA has 10 files I want to download all the ten to localfolder directory which I mentioned in  s3.getObject(params).createReadStream().pipe(ws);

My code :

```
const downloadObject = () => {
  var params = { Bucket: "Sample", Key:"folderA/"};
  const ws = fs.createWriteStream(`${__dirname}/localfolder/`);
  const s3Stream = s3.getObject(params).createReadStream().pipe(ws);
  s3Stream.on("error", (err) => {
    ws.end();
  });
  s3Stream.on("close", () => {
    console.log(`downloaded successfully from s3 at ${new Date()}`);
    ws.end();
  });
};
```

expected output:

s3 -> bucket/folderA/<10 files>
localmachine -> localfolder/<need all 10 files in local>

Answer (score 0):

There is quite alot to it,

Firstly you would need to list all buckets, then loop over all the buckets (if you only want one fine). Create a local directory if not found etc.

Then find out all files in the bucket and then loop over them, on each path you the get the object and store it.

Here is how would do it with the [minio js client](https://docs.min.io/docs/javascript-client-api-reference.html) (the calls would be the same) tweak it to your needs obviously the folder paths would be different.

```
/**
 * S3 images pull script
 */

const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const util = require('util')
const readFile = util.promisify(fs.readFile)
const writeFile = util.promisify(fs.writeFile)

//
const rootPath = path.join(__dirname, '..')
const publicPath = path.join(rootPath, 'public', 'images')

//
require('dotenv').config({
  path: path.join(rootPath, '.env')
})

// minio client S3
const s3 = new(require('minio')).Client({
  endPoint: process.env.S3_HOST,
  port: parseInt(process.env.S3_PORT, 10),
  useSSL: process.env.S3_USE_SSL === 'true',
  accessKey: process.env.S3_ACCESS_KEY,
  secretKey: process.env.S3_ACCESS_SECRET,
  region: process.env.S3_REGION
})

/**
 * Functions
 */

const mkdir = dirPath => {
  dirPath.split(path.sep).reduce((prevPath, folder) => {
    const currentPath = path.join(prevPath, folder, path.sep);
    if (!fs.existsSync(currentPath)) {
      fs.mkdirSync(currentPath);
    }
    return currentPath
  }, '')
}

// list objects in bucket
const listObjects = bucket => new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
  //
  bucket.objects = []
  bucket.total_objects = 0
  bucket.total_size = 0
  //
  let stream = await s3.listObjectsV2(bucket.name, '', true)
  //
  stream.on('data', obj => {
    if (obj && (obj.name || obj.prefix)) {
      bucket.objects.push(obj)
      bucket.total_objects++
      bucket.total_size = bucket.total_size + obj.size
    }
  })
  //
  stream.on('end', () => resolve(bucket))
  stream.on('error', e => reject(e))
})

// get an objects data
const getObject = (bucket, name) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  s3.getObject(bucket, name, (err, stream) => {
    if (err) reject(err)
    //
    let chunks = []
    stream.on('data', chunk => chunks.push(chunk))
    stream.on('end', () => resolve(Buffer.concat(chunks || [])))
    stream.on('error', e => reject(e))
  })
})

/**
 *
 */
async function main() {

  // get buckets
  console.log(`Fetching buckets from: ${process.env.S3_HOST}`)
  let buckets = []
  try {
    buckets = await s3.listBuckets()

    console.log(buckets.length + ' buckets found')
  } catch (e) {
    return console.error(e)
  }

  // create local folders if not exists
  console.log(`Creating local folders in ./api/public/images/ if not exists`)
  try {
    for (let bucket of buckets) {
      //
      bucket.local = path.join(publicPath, bucket.name)
      try {
        await fs.promises.access(bucket.local)
      } catch (e) {
        if (e.code === 'ENOENT') {
          console.log(`Creating local folder: ${bucket.local}`)
          await fs.promises.mkdir(bucket.local)
        } else
          bucket.error = e.message
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {
    return console.error(e)
  }

  // fetch all bucket objects
  console.log(`Populating bucket objects`)
  try {
    for (let bucket of buckets) {
      bucket = await listObjects(bucket)
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }

  // loop over buckets and download all objects
  try {
    for (let bucket of buckets) {
      console.log(`Downloading bucket: ${bucket.name}`)
      // loop over and download
      for (let object of bucket.objects) {
        // if object name has prefix
        let dir = path.dirname(object.name)
        if (dir !== '.') {
          try {
            await fs.promises.access(path.join(bucket.local, dir))
          } catch (e) {
            if (e.code === 'ENOENT') {
              console.log(`Creating local folder: ${bucket.local}`)
              mkdir(path.join(bucket.local, dir))
            }
          }
        }

        //
        console.log(`Downloading object[${bucket.name}]: ${object.name}`)
        await writeFile(path.join(bucket.local, object.name), await getObject(bucket.name, object.name))
      }
    }

    console.log(`Completed!`)
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}

main()
```