# how to download all files in an s3 folder using AWS Javascript/Node SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-js

I currently have multiple files under a folder in an s3 bucket that I wish to download all at once into a local folder (created during run time) using javascript/node sdk.

My attempt is below:

```
import { S3 } from 'aws-sdk';
const s3 = new S3();
const obj = {
      Bucket: `my-bucket`,
      Key: `my-folder/`,
};
const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('/downloadedFiles');
s3.getObject(obj)
    .createReadStream()
    .pipe(writeStream);
```

When I run this code I get an error saying `Error: EROFS: read-only file system, open '/downloadedFiles'` which I suspect is because the argument for `createWriteStream` must take in an actual file. If I change it to something like `file.py` and run the code again I get `NoSuchKey: The specified key does not exist.` so I know that for the `getObject` function the key must be an actual file rather than a folder. So my two problems are:

- how do I download an entire folder and not just one file
- how do I download this folder into a local folder that is created at run time

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Related: [How to download all files in aws S3folder in local machine using node js - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63177138/how-to-download-all-files-in-aws-s3folder-in-local-machine-using-node-js)

Comment: There is no API in Amazon S3 that "downloads a folder". You would need to loop through the contents of the folder and download each file separately.